# Safe Transaction API balance - returns 0 for fiatConversion for all tokens

Tags: gnosis-safe, api

I'm trying to fetch the safe address balance with the fiatConversion (USD) but it returns 0 for the all the tokens

https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0x0DA0C3e52C977Ed3cBc641fF02DD271c3ED55aFe/balances/usd/?trusted=false&exclude_spam=false

chainId - 1
fiatCode - usd

expected results
I expect the API response to provide the correct USD value for each token held at the specified safe address.
ie

fiatBalance":"86.0","fiatConversion":"23.0","fiatCode":"USD"

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. We were returning an estimate USD price for the tokens in our transactions service, until last week. With the big amount of tokens it's very difficult for us to maintain that feature. We will move pricing logic to a new service, which is still in progress. In the meantime, if you need a quick replacement, you should go to pricing services like Coingecko.

We started returning zero for every usd token price from our API since last week. It's important to note that by using our official UI you will still see prices, as we integrated coingecko there, but not directly on the transaction service.

Hope it helps!

Best,
Louis